# Adding a new cell to an already existing row

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to insert a new cell using only DOM properties and methods into an already existing row without hard-coding or using an index. I am trying to add a new  tag. The cell needs to go first because I am adding in formation about that corresponds to that row. Any help would be appreciated. So far I have the following:

```js
var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName("music 
        header").nextChild();
        console.log(firstTable);

       var findRow = firstTable.getElementsByTagName("td");
       console.log(findRow);
```

```html
    <div id = "music">
        <h2 id = "music header">Music</h2>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr id = "Hard Rock">
                <td>NEW CELL HERE</td>
                <td>Saint Asonia</td>
                <td>Shinedown</td>
                <td>Breaking Benjamin</td>
                <td>Rise Against</td>
                <td>Three Days Grace</td> 
            </tr>    
            <tr id = "Metal">
                <td>Bullet for my Valentine</td>
                <td>Metallica</td>
                <td>Korn</td>
                <td>Asking Alexandria</td>
                <td>Alexisonfire</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id = "Country">
                <td>Toby Kieth</td>
                <td>Keith Urban</td>
                <td>Taylor Swift</td>
                <td>Kenny Chesney</td>
                <td>Miranda Lambert</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("music header")` should be `getElementById("music header")`, but [*spaces aren't allowed in IDs*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName("music 
    header").nextChild();
console.log(firstTable);
```

isn't going to work because:

1. *getElementsByTagName* expects a tag name, not an ID
2. *getElementsByTagName* returns a (possibly empty) collection, not a single element, and that collection doesn't have a *nextChild* method.
3. *nextChild* is not a valid property of any standard DOM object, perhaps you want [*nextElementSibling*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), which is a property, not a method
4. The id "music header" is invalid as the [ID attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) value can't contain white space.

To find the first table in the document, you can use:

```
var firstTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

To get the first row of the table, you can use:

```
var firstRow = firstTable.rows[0];
```

The index for *rows* can be any value from `0` to `firstTable.rows.length - 1`.

To get the first cell of the row:

```
var firstCell = firstRow.cells[0];
```

What you do next is up to you…

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the parent element and you've found the first child you can try:

```
parent.insertBefore(el, parent.firstChild);
```

Here is the link to the `.insertBefore` docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

and here is the docs for `firstChild` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)

Comment: Since you're new here are some docs for `.querySelector`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector and `.querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know from your question exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. That said, building on Sgnl and RobG's answers and the points the latter made about your structure and references, here is some food for thought.

I assume you want to find the table within a section. You can do that by finding the section first by the id, and then the table beneath that:

```
var firstTable = document.getElementById("music").getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

Your HTML example implies you then want to add a cell to the first row. You can find that row within the previously found table as so:

```
var findRow = firstTable.rows[0];
```

Now that we've found our insert location, let's construct our new cell

```
var newCell = document.createElement("td");
var newTag = document.createElement("span");
var newText = document.createTextNode("NEW CELL HERE");
newCell.appendChild( newTag );
newTag.appendChild( newText );
```

With the node built, let's insert it

```
findRow.insertBefore( newCell, findRow.childNodes[0] );
```

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58352m2j/1) demonstration

Comment: @RobG In respect to what part of the code, sorry? I'm not finding a first child, and only appending a `td` to a `tr`. If I wrap the first `tr` in a `thead` my example still works... I am assuming the first table found with `tagName()[0]` and first row within that table `rows[0]`, but neither of those use `firstChild`

Comment: Too early in the morning… I read *findRow* as *firstTable*. Should have slept in.